# How many Memoria do i need to unlock the Full Story?

Tags: dissidia-final-fantasy-nt

I'm playing Dissidia NT, only in Local/Arcade Mode, and i'm getting Memoria while advancing, using different characters and leveling them up, actually i got 8 Memoria, i could enter on the story mode but i want to know first how many Memoria do i need to unlock the full story, so when i start, i won't be stopped to play from the start to the ending.

On the Story mode menu, there are tons of nodes to unlock, **and i'm asumming every node is 1 Memoria each, but maybe not,** and because i'm not wanting to unlock anything of it yet, i'm asking here.

[image]

Thanks for reading me, i'll be waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 30 Memoria to complete story mode.

Each node and group of nodes cost one Memoria to unlock.
The last node requires 3 Memoria to unlock.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i won't stop playing until i get 30 memoria, already got 12 :)